# Read an image from jni code in android

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI and for my work i need to read an image from sd card(emulator/device) through jni(c++ part) in android. Is this possible or the only way is by passing the image from java part.

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: i'm doing some image processing task in c++ for my android app. For this i want to read an image from sd card in c++ part of my code, but imread is not working

Comment: actualy i'm able to recieve a bitmap from android.... but what i'm looking for is reading the image stored in sd card of emulator from c++ part, and not receiving it as a bitmap

Comment: Saying that your read "is not working" doesn't help us understand what you're doing or what is going wrong. You need to be more explicit about what isn't working and why it's failing, e.g. paste some code in your question, point out the exact line that's failing, and specify the errno value or error log message.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass image from java. Just open image as normal binary file in C++.

```
FILE* File = fopen("/sdcard/image/img.png" , "rb" );

// Your implementation here

fclose( File );
```